# Does the shopping cart model encapsulate shopping cart items?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, magento-1, quote, certification

I'm currently preparing to take my Magento Certified Developer test next Tuesday. A couple of the practice tests I have encountered have the following question:

> *Which object never encapsulates any shopping cart items?* 
>   A. Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart 
>   B. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote 
>   C. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address<type=shipping> 
>   D. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address<type=billing> 
>   **Answer: B**

Why would that be the correct answer? `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` has shopping cart items that are associated with it (`$_items` property, `getAllItems() and getItemsCollection()` methods). Perhaps I don't properly understand what is meant by encapsulation - what would be the meaning of encapsulation in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(B) makes the least sense. (A), (C) and (D) all give transitive **access** to shopping cart items through `getQuote()->getItemsCollection()`, but the quote itself (B) is the object that **encapsulates** the item collection.

To me that looks like there's a mistake in the practice question and the "never" should not be there.

---

About "encapsulation": In software development this is related to *information hiding* and usually refers to private properties.

Comment: Pretty sure the Address encapsulates some quote items here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php#L430

Comment: OK, that counts if you call them "cart items" as well

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native english speaker but to me here "encapsulate" means "contain".

I think the answer to this question is `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart`. **As you can see from this class, it never encapsulates any shopping cart items but it encapsulates quotes (from `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`) which themselves encapsulates shopping cart items.**